# Как выкинуть ошибку валидации при загрузке FileField/ImageField, если файл по пути сохранения уже существует?

Tags: python, django

Сабж, в админке Django.

```
class FooModel(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(
        upload_to="foo/path/images",
        validators=[здесь_попытка_в_валидатор]
    )
```

Хотел заюзать что-то вроде `os.path.exists` в кастомном валидаторе, но, во-первых, не нашёл как отличить свежезалитый файл от уже сохранённого в модели, и во-вторых, не нашёл путь, в который будет сохранён файл (`.path` в валидаторе игнорирует прописанный `upload_to` и выдаёт бредятину относительно MEDIA_ROOT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `validators` не получиться. В валидаторе Вы не сможите получить старое значение поля объекта.
Вам необходимо переопределить форму, а в ней уже, в методе `clean_image` делать проверки. Думаю, старое значение можно будет получить через `self.instance.image`.
Как-то так:

```
class FooAdminForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    def clean_image(self):
        old_fullname = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.instance.image.name)
        if os.path.exists(old_fullname):
            raise ValidationError(u'...')
        return self.cleaned_data.get("image", False)

class FooOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    form = FooAdminForm
```